# Pycharm external tool for Cython compiling does not find Cython module

Tags: python, pycharm, cython

I'm trying to learn to work with Cython, but I have some problems starting up.
Specifically, I followed [this](https://geoexamples.com/python/2017/04/20/pycharm-cython.html) guide to setup the external tool in pycharm to be able to (re)compile the .pyx files easily which uses the command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace`. However, it gives the following error when I try to use it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Cython.Build import cythonize
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cython'
```

I don't understand this, as I did install the Cython module in the project. Also, running exactly the same command in the terminal does work.
Can someone help me to make this work? It looks to me like it has something to do with pycharm/how the external tool executes the command, but I have no clue what the problem exactly is.

Answer (score 0):

hi you probably need to install the `Cython` package into your environment as well:

`$ pip install Cython`